# qt creator c++ compiling

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5, qmake

I have started to learn Qt and created .cpp file, as it explained in this [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html). Then I open a command promt and type next commands:

> qmake -project
>
> qmake
>
> make

After first two lines everething is ok, but after third line it gives an error:

> Makefile:62: ***multiple target patterns. Stop.

Comment: What main.cpp do you have that reproduces the issue? Have you tried to pass the proper -spec? Also, can you show the generated project file? Is it Linux or Windows with mingw? Which Qt version is this?

Comment: What has your problem to do with the qt creator?

Comment: You don't need to use a command prompt if you are developing with QtCreator. Once you have [configured qtcreator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-configuring.html) you build and run using the icons.

Comment: @VascoRinaldo: it is run in the QtCreator command prompt as per OP's explanation.

Comment: @LaszloPapp main.cpp is similar as in the tutorial(see link in the question). `.pro` file has the next lines: `TEMPLATE=app` `TARGET=tutorials` `INCLUDEPATH+=.` `SOURCES+=main.cpp`. I use Windows with mingw. Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit). I use QTCreator command promt, but it gives the same error with Windows command promt. Unfortunately I don't know what the proper -spec is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment: `I use Windows with mingw. Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)`

That is wrong. You seem to be mixing the MSVC based Qt installation with mingw. You cannot do that. Mingw and MSVC are different compilers. They are not ABI compatible, nor are their makefiles compatible.

That also explains the issue since you will have path issues in the makefile itself as the gnu and windows makefiles are slightly different in that regard.

You should install the mingw version of Qt or build yourself.

On a side note: you seem to be reading a Qt 4 example, whereas you are trying to use Qt 5. In Qt 5, the widgets were put into their own widgets module. That does not get added to the project file automatically, so you will need to add `QT+=widgets` manually.

Edit: seems you have misled us, and you do have a mingw version installed. Once that is done, you should execute the following command then:

```
qmake -r -spec win32-g++
```

`-r`: it will go through the subdirectories, i.e. it will be recursive.
`-spec win32-g++`: this will tell qmake to generate GNU makefile.

That being said, you should look into [how to set up a kit in QtCreator](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-targets.html&ei=JTKDU6rZFuau7Aa98IDwCQ&usg=AFQjCNHupfsz92OVqDJgIfAM8vg9RgWluQ&sig2=CBw5s2aWEYIQ1WCLTDJS4w&bvm=bv.67720277,d.ZGU). It is better than using qmake from the command prompt.

Comment: Actually, I have installed `qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482_opengl-5.3.0`, but when I go to `Help->About Qt Creator` it gives that information about `MSVC 2010, 32 bit`. I have manually added `QT+=widgets` it still doesn't work in qt command promt, however it works in Qt Creator.

Comment: `qmake -r -spec win32-g++` doesn't help, `make` gives the same error. You wrote: ` look into how to set up a kit in QtCreator. It is better than using qmake from the command prompt.` Actually, kit is setted up and I can compile and run tutorial examples from Qt Creator (after adding 'QT+=widgets' line into .pro file ). I just don't understand why Qt command promt qives an error.

Comment: @lnk: remove the makefile before running that command, i.e. start it from scratch. You can also always check in the output window what QtCreator runs for you and compare.

Comment: I have checked my `Path` variable and found that it contains: `C:\cygwin64\bin` it is cygwin compiler which I used for NetBeans, and the `make` command was called from that path. So, now I type `mingw32-make` instead of `make` and everething is ok.

Comment: @lnk: great to hear. Thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

I build this example with Qt 4.8. and mingw 4.7:

For example go to subdir part1 and try the following:

```
qmake -project
qmake -spec win32-g++
make
```

This should work the same way with Qt 5, too.

Comment: For subdirs, it is better to use `-r`. That is also what QtCreator is doing by default AFAIK.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I'm talking not about the Template Subdirs and not about the "gsqt.pro". If you go into one of the subdirs (for Example "part1") and build the Project than this works and you need no -r option.

Comment: No, it will not if the subdirs have subdirs, or the subdirs are not buildable on their own, no. Why do you think QtCreator adds that by default?